# Validate phone number start with 0 and must be 8 or 9 or 10 digits

Tags: regex

Below is my regex pattern..

```
/^0[0-9]\d{8}$/g
```

This pattern will allow any number start with 0 and must have 8 digits.

However, what I need is start with 0 and must have 8 or 9 or digits.

How to do that?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to have the `[0-9]` as `\d` does the same thing. I have laid out solutions depending on your exact request as you seem to have two different requests. Is it 8 to 9 digits or 8 to 10 digits, and does this total include the initial `0`? See below for solutions to both:

**Case 1:**

> must be 8 or 9 or 10 digits

Try:

```
/^0\d{7,9}$/ // or /^0\d{8,10}$/ if not including the initial 0 in the count
```

**Case 2:**

> start with 0 and must have 8 or 9 or digits.

Try:

```
/^0\d{8,9}$/ // if the 8 or 9 digits does not include the initial 0 for the count
/^0\d{7,8}$/ // if the 8 or 9 digits does include the initial 0 for the count
```

Details:

`{8,9}` specifies matching 8 or 9 characters of the preceding token.

If the total number of digits includes the initial `0`, then simply replace `{8,9}` with `{7,8}` (that way the total number of digits is 8 or 9). If you want the range to be 8 to 10, as mentioned in the title, then instead of `{8,9}`, use `{8,10}`. Again, this would be `{7,9}` instead if not accounting for the initial `0`.

**[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hE6sB5/2)**